# How to recovery files from a damaged Windows instalation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, data-recovery

My Windows 7 installation won't start, so I need to reinstall it. But I have some important files in the Desktop, and I can't back these up using a Ubuntu LiveCD. I can enter every folder except my user folder inside the "User" directory. Maybe it's compressed/encrypted (though I don't use a password)?

How should I back these files up when I can't seem to access them?

Comment: What does it say when you try to enter `User`?

Comment: See [How to decrypt Windows 7 encrypted files](http://superuser.com/q/314579) if the issue is indeed encryption

Comment: It takes a long loading and, at the end, it gives an error. I don't remember now.

Comment: It would be really helpful to know the error. Linux doesn't care about Windows access control lists, therefore, linux should be able to access your files if they're still valid files.

Answer (score 0):

Attach storage to put the files on to the PC.  USB stick, external hdd,internal hdd, or whatever.  Put your "Windows install disc" in and boot from it.  After selecting "Repair" you should have a menu with about 5 items on it.

Use "command prompt".
Then see if you can navigate to the correct folder.

copy the files to wherever if you want.